# Access to PropertyName of object itself as string

Tags: javascript

I have object define like this

```
var obj = { abcdefghijkl: 'abcdefghijkl', other_key: 1234 };
```

Can I define object for get property name itself as string in Javascript ? Like this

```
var obj = { abcdefghijkl: getSelfPropertyName, other_key: 1234 };
```

I don't want for `this.abcdefghijkl`

Comment: please add a use case.

Comment: You mean to avoid typing it twice? If you have it as a variable, you can do this: `var obj = {[my_string]: my_string, other_key: 1234}`, but you can't get it in the way you're showing. Also, the example I showed uses ES6 syntax, so old browsers won't handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem that one can typically solve with variants of construction patterns. Lets use a classic approach.

```js
function MyObject(...props){
  props.forEach((p,i) => this[p] = i ? "default value" : p);
}

var obj = new MyObject("abcdefghijkl", "other_prop", "yet_another_one");
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 3):

> Can I define object for get property name itself as string in Javascript?

No, there's no shortcut mechanism that lets you define a property with a value the same as the property name *within* an object initializer.

You *can* do it in a two-step:

```js
var s = "abcdefghijkl";
var obj = {other_key: 1234};
obj[s] = s;
console.log(obj);
```

If you absolutely, positively have to do it in a single expression, you can use a temporary function, but it's not pretty:

```js
var obj = (function(s) {
  var o = {other_key: 1234};
  o[s] = s;
  return o;
})("abcdefghijkl");
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Thanks you @T.J.Crowder You help me safe my time.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an ES6 feature, [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)

```js
var obj = { abcdefghijkl: 'getSelfPropertyName', other_key: 1234 },
    p = new Proxy(obj, {
        get: function(target, prop) {
            return target[prop] === 'getSelfPropertyName' ? prop : target[prop];
        }
    });
   
console.log(p.abcdefghijkl); // 'abcdefghijkl'
```